# Rest API Get using swift 3 playground

Tags: swift3

Please assist in figuring out how do I make REST API GET/POST/DELETE/PUT using swift 3 and in playground.

Examples I got from search don't work as expacted. Also I want to consume Laravel REST API first using GET method.

```
import Foundation

let headers = ["content-type": "application/json"]

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8088/api/person")! as URL,
                                        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.httpBody = postData as Data

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print(error)
  } else {
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse)
  }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: I am trying to call this code from Playground file.. I want to test it before i start using the code in my app

Answer (score 1):

To run asynchronous code in a Playground you have to add these two lines

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

You are mixing up GET and POST semantics.

- In a GET request the parameters are included in the URL (`http://example.com/api?key1=value1&key2=value2`)
- In a POST request the parameters are passed in the HTTP body

---

Note: In Swift 3+ don't use `NSURL` and `NSMutableURLRequest`. Use the native API